# Find a basis for a specific set of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let X = $\{p \in P_2(\mathbb{R}): p'(-1)-2 \int_0^1 p(x) dx = 0\}$

I need to find a basis for X and demonstrate that it is a basis.  So far I have deduced that the polynomials in the set must satisfy $c = (-4/3)a$ , so they must be of the form $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + (-4/3)a$.

How do I determine the vectors in the basis X working from the standard basis for $P^2$ of $\{1,x,x^2\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have found the formula for how the polynomial should look like it is easy. Note that in your formula $a$ and $b$ have to satisfy no constraints: so take $f(x)$ corresponding to $a=1,b=0$ and $g(x)$ corresponding $a=0,b=1$, then $\{f(x). g(x)\}$ should be a basis i.e. $\{x^2- 4/3, x\}$ for $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One more thing if you don't mind - how come the basis only has 2 elements when the standard basis for $P^2$ has 3 elements? That's the main part that was confusing me

Comment: In a vector space of dimension $n$, any proper subset which is a subspace can have at most dimension $n-1$. Here you have to check that not every polynomial satisfies the defining condition, so it is a proper subspace.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense; I was treating it as the actual vector space. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are there 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) = a\left( \color{blue}{x^2- \frac{4}{3}} \right)+b \color{red}{x}. 
\end{eqnarray*}
So your basis is $\{ \color{blue}{x^2- \frac{4}{3}} , \color{red}{x} \}$. Now verify that each of these satifies the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

In the standard basis an element of $X$ is a vector of components:
$$
(a,b,-\frac{4}{3}a)^T=a\left(1,0,-\frac{4}{3}\right)^T+b(0,1,0)^T
$$

Comment: Telling beginning students in linear algebra to conflate elements of a vector space with their coordinate vectors relative to some basis (even a standard basis) is a really bad idea. I can tell you from teaching and tutoring experience that it leads to enormous confusion.

Comment: @ChristianSykes: I simply suggest  a possible way to approach the problem that, in my opinion, can be instructive just because explicitly illustrate what the components of a polynomial are. But I agree that it is important to well understand that a vector is not simply the set of its components.